# zsh custom completion file not sourced properly

Tags: zsh, path, autocomplete, dot-files

I encountered a strange behaviour regarding ZSH completion for my custom script and need some ideas, what went wrong and how to solve it.

I have written a little custom script `myscript` and also created a corresponding completion script `_myscript`. The latter begins with the following lines as usual: `#compdef myscript` (also tried `#compdef _myscript myscript` with same result). At the beginning I had both files inside my `~/.local/bin` directory, which is part of my `$PATH`. I also added it to my `$fpath` so ZSH could find the completion script.

So far, so good. Everything worked fine with the completion of the `myscript` command. But then I moved both files to my **.dotfiles** to share them through the corresponding git repo. My dotfiles contain a folder for completion script which is also part of my `$fpath`. But when moved to this subdirectory of my dotfiles, completions stopped working...

I removed `.zcompdump` to renew the completion assignments and tested different syntax to add the directory to my `$fpath`, but nothing helped. I also called `compinit` manually after removing `.zcompdump` to be sure it is called after all assingments were executed.

The first strange thing is, that other completion scripts inside the dotfile directory are recongnised by ZSH completion system as it also contains the completion scripts for my `rustup` and `cargo` command. When grepping `.zcompdump` after the different steps I tried, it always shows the assignments for both those commands but not for `myscript`.

The second strange behaviour is, that when I move the completion script back to the `~/.local/bin` dir and restart ZSH, it suddenly recocgnises the script and completions start working again. And now I can also grep it inside my `.zcompdump`

Now I'm running out of ideas what could be the reason, especially since `rustup` and `cargo` completion is working properly from the same directory. It would be much more comfortable to have all my custom completion working from my dotfiles, so I can use them on different machines without much manual configuration. Of course, I know I could hardcode the completion assignment inside my `zshrc`, but thats also not as portable as the regular `fpath` It may be a minor aspect I'm missing, but hopefully someone knows the solution.

I can't offer much code, since it seems not to be due to my scripts code. JFYI: I'm running Manjaro Linux (with predefined ZSH setting, which I already checked).

Comment: Weird. My first tip would have been to remove `.zcompdump`, because zsh has a heuristic to reconstruct it which is if the number of available files change, and that doesn't catch moving a file (or changing what commands it offers). Can you confirm that zsh is using `~/.zcompdump`? (`echo $_comp_dumpfile`) Maybe try tracing zsh's startup and comparing the two cases (temporarily add `rm ~/.zcompdump; set -x` at the top of your `.zshrc`). Also try setting `HOME` to a different directory where you've just copied a minimum set of relevant files, see if it behaves the same.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' for your suggestions. But as mentioned below it was all an unrecognised typo added by the autocompletion of my editor... But those things are often the most overlooked reasons :D

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, absolutely my bad.**

When I edited my `zshrc` with neovim and created a variable holding the path to my dotfiles, neovims autocompletion added an extra slash `/` at the end of the string; what I didn't recognised. Using that variable as substring for adding the directory holding the completion script to the `fpath` added an unecessary double slash. Thus, ZSH was searching the wrong directory...

The only strange thing remaining is the fact that completion for `rustup` and `cargo` still worked with the wrong path. But that was not the question...